# How can I fix Google Or-Tools solution problem when i use TimeWindows matrix?

Tags: java, spring, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I use Google Or-Tools VehicleRoutingProblem with timeWindows, 
when I try to use the "time window" the solution becomes either zero, or it gives an error on

`timeDimension.cumulVar (index) .setRange (data.timeWindows [i] [0], data.timeWindows [i] [1]);` 
line. I cost all double to long values ​​and then transfer all the data. since all the code is written in C ++ I cannot follow the code. Who can help.

I add the code of my test and two files with matix.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lKYQep_yppJP3rhY_n-vZIvKJDbcrfpj/view?usp=sharing `distance and duration matrix`

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13K6jrnG4QIL1FQw8UxlaWA3rn4RoX7fo/view?usp=sharing `time windows`

```
import com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.*;
import com.google.protobuf.Duration;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class OrToolsTests3 {


    private static long[][] data;
    private static long[][] timeWindows;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OrToolsTests3.class.getName());


    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
    }


    // [START data_model]
    class DataModel {
        public final long[][] durationMatrix = data;
        public final long[][] timeWindows = OrToolsTests3.timeWindows;
        public final int vehicleNumber = 1;
        public final int depot = 0;
    }
    // [END data_model]

    // [START solution_printer]
    /// @brief Print the solution.
    void printSolution(
            DataModel data, RoutingModel routing, RoutingIndexManager manager, Assignment solution) {
        RoutingDimension timeDimension = routing.getMutableDimension("Time");
        long totalTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.vehicleNumber; ++i) {
            long index = routing.start(i);
            logger.info("Route for Vehicle " + i + ":");
            String route = "";
            while (!routing.isEnd(index)) {
                IntVar timeVar = timeDimension.cumulVar(index);
                route += manager.indexToNode(index) + " Time(" + solution.min(timeVar) + ","
                        + solution.max(timeVar) + ") -> ";
                index = solution.value(routing.nextVar(index));
            }
            IntVar timeVar = timeDimension.cumulVar(index);
            route += manager.indexToNode(index) + " Time(" + solution.min(timeVar) + ","
                    + solution.max(timeVar) + ")";
            logger.info(route);
            logger.info("Time of the route: " + solution.min(timeVar) + "min");
            totalTime += solution.min(timeVar);
        }
        logger.info("Total time of all routes: " + totalTime + "min");
    }

    // [END solution_printer]
    @Test
    public void main() throws Exception {
        // Instantiate the data problem.
        // [START data]
        final DataModel data = new DataModel();
        // [END data]

        // Create Routing Index Manager
        // [START index_manager]
        RoutingIndexManager manager =
                new RoutingIndexManager(data.durationMatrix.length, data.vehicleNumber, data.depot);
        // [END index_manager]

        // Create Routing Model.
        // [START routing_model]
        RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(manager);
        // [END routing_model]

        // Create and register a transit callback.
        // [START transit_callback]
        final int transitCallbackIndex =
                routing.registerTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) -> {
                    // Convert from routing variable Index to user NodeIndex.
                    int fromNode = manager.indexToNode(fromIndex);
                    int toNode = manager.indexToNode(toIndex);
                    return data.durationMatrix[fromNode][toNode];
                });
        // [END transit_callback]

        // Define cost of each arc.
        // [START arc_cost]
        routing.setArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);
        // [END arc_cost]

        // Add Time constraint.
        // [START time_constraint]
        routing.addDimension(transitCallbackIndex, // transit callback
                30, // allow waiting time
                30, // vehicle maximum capacities
                false, // start cumul to zero
                "Time");
        RoutingDimension timeDimension = routing.getMutableDimension("Time");
        // Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
        for (int i = 1; i < data.timeWindows.length; ++i) {
            long index = manager.nodeToIndex(i);
            timeDimension.cumulVar(index).setRange(data.timeWindows[i][0], data.timeWindows[i][1]);
        }
        // Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.vehicleNumber; ++i) {
            long index = routing.start(i);
            timeDimension.cumulVar(index).setRange(data.timeWindows[0][0], data.timeWindows[0][1]);
        }
        // [END time_constraint]

        // Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
        // [START depot_start_end_times]
        for (int i = 0; i < data.vehicleNumber; ++i) {
            routing.addVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(timeDimension.cumulVar(routing.start(i)));
            routing.addVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(timeDimension.cumulVar(routing.end(i)));
        }
        // [END depot_start_end_times]

        // Setting first solution heuristic.
        // [START parameters]
        RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters =
                main.defaultRoutingSearchParameters()
                        .toBuilder()
                        .setTimeLimit(Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(5).build())
                        .setFirstSolutionStrategy(FirstSolutionStrategy.Value.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
                        .build();
        // [END parameters]

        // Solve the problem.
        // [START solve]
        Assignment solution = routing.solveWithParameters(searchParameters);
        // [END solve]

        // Print solution on console.
        // [START print_solution]
        printSolution(data, routing, manager, solution);
        // [END print_solution]
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right. I've been struggling with time windows and I don't think the way you fix them is wrong.

Make sure the waiting time (setted when routing.addDimension) is not lower than the time between two fixed time windows.

Say if you have a location at 9 and the next location is fixed at 10, your waiting time of 30 is not enough to solve the problem